# Fetch data from table join using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

In the table 'users_subjects' I am relating the tables 'subjects' and 'users'.

All the of the table data is introduced from PHP in such a way that when a `user` and `subjects` are introduced, the '`users_subjects`' table is created.

For example, if I enter a user named 'EXAMPLE' with ID = 1 and SAT and ICT subjects with IDs 1 and 2, the '`users_subjects`' table would look similar to the following:

[image]

The problem is that I'm trying to show the users with their corresponding subjects in a PHP table, but I don't know how to show the subjects separated by commas in the "SUBJECT" column. I would like to do something like the following image. Can someone help me? Thank you

[image]

This is what I have in my code:

```
 <table class="users">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><h2>USERS</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> NAME </th>
        <th> SUBJECTS </th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rol='profesor'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows==0){

    echo 'No users';
}else{
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


     $subjects = "";
        $sql2 = "SELECT user_id_fk, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id_fk SEPARATOR ',') FROM users_subjects WHERE user_id_fk='$id' GROUP BY user_id_fk;";

        /*$sql2 = "SELECT user_id_fk, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id_fk SEPARATOR ',') FROM users_subjects where user_id_fk='$id'";*/


        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $subjects = $row2["subject"];
        }

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$row["username"]."</td>
                  <td>".$subjects."</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at the GROUP_CONCAT function

Comment: there is no `subject` column in your table, just `subject_name`. Than you have errors in your SQL query (missing aliases at tables, etc).

Comment: @panther sorry it was an error, I have just edited it

Comment: @ana: still incorrect SQL query, missing aliases at tables... check SQL error. `GROUP_CONCAT` or `IMPLODE` (first or the second one) is good way, check `$result->...` vs. `$result2->...`, etc. PHP/SQL degbugging basics, make an effort a little bit...

Comment: @ana: check SQL errors and try to understand PHP/SQL basics!

Comment: If you have MyISAM tables, you really should move those to InnoDB. Likewise, unless you have a very compelling reason, use `utf8mb4` in preference to the strictly 8-bit `latin1` character encoding.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your comments, I just changed the Engine type to InnoDB, with `ALTER TABLE users_subjects ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: Don't forget the character encoding, too, or else you won't be able to handle non-Latin characters or emoji. 

Comment: @tadman Sure! I changed it again with `ALTER TABLE users_subjects CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` Thank you. About using `parameterized queries` and `bind_param` I'm on it but first I'm trying to get the code to work

Answer (score 1):

The query you need must involve grouping to use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT user_id_fk, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id_fk SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM users_subjects
  WHERE user_id_fk=?
  GROUP BY user_id_fk
```

If you want to get the names, you need to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.username, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.subject SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM users_subjects
  RIGHT JOIN users ON users.id=users_subjects.user_id_fk
  RIGHT JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id=users_subjects.subject_id_fk
  WHERE user_id_fk=?
  GROUP BY user_id_fk
```

Comment: I edited the code, you mean like that? But still not working sorry :S

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afe7a0/2) so maybe you can explain in more detail the problem you're having.

Comment: I'm constantly getting an error in `$subjects = $row2["subject"];`  where it shows: `Notice: Undefined index: subject` I changed many things but I still get the same error

Comment: The only values you'll get back are those you ask for specifically. If you `SELECT x,y` you won't magically get `z`. Use `var_dump` to find out for sure, but as a general rule, each column has a name based on the query to generate it. In this case you may need to do `GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS subjects` to give it a much shorter name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try what you say. I have tried with `GROUP_CONCAT (...) AS subjects` and at least it doesn't give me the error of **Undefined index: subject**, now it shows me in all rows the number **13**, this is very rare.

Comment: The key to understanding result sets is each set consists of *zero or more rows* that contain *one or more columns, each of which has a name corresponding to the `SELECT` criteria used*. That is in this query you have keys `"username"` and `"subjects"` and *nothing else*. If you want other columns you *must* select them as well. Use `var_dump` to verify the names before using them.